# Python ZMQ send/receive zip file

Tags: python, zeromq, pyzmq

I'm trying to use 0MQ (ZMQ) to receive a zip file:

```
fileBuffer = dataSocket.recv()
dataSocket.send("2") #Send success signal
filename = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'programs', 'newProg.zip')
filehandle = open(filename, "w")
filehandle.write(fileBuffer)
filehandle.close()
```

The file appears in the right place, however it is corrupt - Windows claims it's empty when trying to extract it and when opening it, says it's corrupt. Am I missing some kind of encoding in the file? Or something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to use the Frame's [buffer](https://zeromq.github.io/pyzmq/api/zmq.html#zmq.Frame.buffer) you may have to state it explicitly like

```
fileBuffer = dataSocket.recv(copy=False).buffer()
```

Remember that `recv(copy)` is True by default which would return a string rather than a Frame:

> **recv(flags=0, copy=True, track=False)**
>
> *copy : bool* ... If False a Frame object is returned, if True a string copy of message is returned.